Crittall Window on Timber Subframe Replacement Options
Need some advice. I want to replace some old crittal window on my 1920s property. It is in a conservation area so uPVC is out, and we also want to keep the traditional look as much as possible. One box/bay window and a normal casement window on top
These old Crittall windows are on a timber subframe that has some paint flaking, but doesn't seem overall rotten.
After browsing around, seems like Aluminum and Timber are the only options. I think Timber would fit the bill but it is really expensive.
The problem with Aluminum, even slimline, is that I fear this is going to look awful. Both my partner and I like the Timber subframe, particularly in the bay window with the vertical posts namely. Our neighbours who have an identical property replaced theirs with Aluminum, but it seems super flat and ugly.  The corners are not recessed anymore, and overall it just looks bland
Photos attached are my property (red brick) and neighbours (white).
Any advice? Can I install aluminum windows retrofiting onto the existing timber frame? Is there some way to add depth to the window / keep the vertical posts in the corners if replaced with Aluminum?
(https://ibb.co/c34xrz2)
(https://ibb.co/52qmBGg)

It sounds 100% like you should repaint your windows.
